# Build fails on VSTS with error connect ETIMEDOUT 52.173.242.81:8080, on jenkins build is successfully executed

Tags: jenkins, build, azure-devops

I'm trying out DevOps with VSTS, Docker and Java and I'm stuck with failing builds PFA screenshots  of the same.

VSTS build failing while Queue Jenkins job task

[image]

Job is successfully executed on Jenkins and .War file is also produced.

This has been setup on Azure following document 
https://github.com/msdevno/hol-oss-devops

Comment: Do you use Hosted agent? Could you access your Jenkins from build agent? (The Jenkins need to be accessible from internet if using hosted agent) What's the detail build log? Can you share the detail build log on the OneDrive?

Comment: @Staratin-MSFT, Yes I'm using  hosted agent for build, Code is on GitHub, Manually I'm queuing the build and it triggers the build on Jenkins (Linux VM on Azure) and on Jenkins build is successfully executed and .war file is getting generated and same is not getting updated on VSTS build status. I guess there's one way communication happening from VSTS to Jenkins other way it's not. [logs on onedrive](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkUrJ7uHTBFca0PiQr_NbnMw20s). This is my service end point URL (http://52.176.101.208:8080), here is the URL when VSTS triggers Jenkins job .

Comment: And here is the IP addreess with URL which was availabe with error mesage. createRootJob(): http://52.173.242.81:8080/queue/item/22/api/json . One more thing is when I created this VM it was having Dynamic Public IP later i Changed to Static IP . Not sure why it is taking this old IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the above issue.
My guess worked out correct.
Changing the Public IP from Dynamic to Static caused this issue.
Looked into Jenkins configuration(Manange Jenkins > Configure System > Jenkins Location > Jenkins URL) This was containing dynamic IP and now I've changed it to new static IP and voila it works fine. Build Succeeds and status updated on VSTS as well :)

Thanks for sparing your time in looking to my issue @Starain-MSFT & @Donovan

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to have the commit to VSTS trigger the build in Jenkins. Then have Jenkins trigger the release in VSTS.  [Setting up CI/CD with the TFS Plugin for Jenkins](http://www.donovanbrown.com/post/Setting-up-CICD-with-the-TFS-Plugin-for-Jenkins) This would not require using VSTS for build.

Comment: My Source Code is on GitHub and Jenkins on Azure Linux VM. When I queue the build, it is executed successfully on Jenkins and .war file is generated, the status is not getting updated on VSTS and build eventually fails with time out error. Pls. look in my comment about changing VM public from Dynamic to Static , is it creating any issue here? Pls. let me know your inputs.